# Spring Boot Batch - Stop and Start a multithreaded step with CompositeItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am trying to stop and start a multithreaded step through Scheduler. But I am getting exception as

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unexpected cursor position change.
```

If I understand correctly we wont be able to restart an multithreaded step. But I am not restarting. I stop the job by **stepExecution.setTerminateOnly()** through **ChunkListener()** and trying to start this by **jobLauncher.run()** in a scheduler. Here is my codes;

```
public class BatchConfiguration {
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
        
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;
    
        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
            SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("user_purge");
            asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
            return asyncTaskExecutor;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Job userPurgeJob() {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("userPurgeJob")
                    .start(userPurgeStep())
                    .listener(new JobLoggerListener())
                    .build();
        }   
            
        @Bean
        public Step userPurgeStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("userPurgeStep")
                    .<UserInfo, UserInfo> chunk(10)
                    .reader(userPurgeReader())
                    .writer(compositePurgeWriter())
                    .listener(new StopListener())
                    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                    .build();
        }
        
        
        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public JdbcCursorItemReader<UserInfo> userPurgeReader(){
            JdbcCursorItemReader<UserInfo> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<UserInfo>();
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setSql("SELECT user_id, user_status "
                    + "FROM db3.user_purge "
                    + "WHERE user_status = 'I' "
                    + "AND purge_status = 'N'");
            reader.setRowMapper(new SoftDeleteMapper());
      
            return reader;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public CompositeItemWriter<UserInfo> compositePurgeWriter() {
            CompositeItemWriter<UserInfo> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
            compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(delMasterWriter(), delTableWriter()));
            return compositeItemWriter;
        }
        
            
        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> delMasterWriter() {
            JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo>();
            writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
            writer.setSql("UPDATE db3.userinfo "
                    + "SET user_status = :userStatus, "
                        + "updated = NOW() "
                        + "WHERE user_id = :userId");
            writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
            
            return writer;
        }
        
        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> delTableWriter() {
            JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<UserInfo>();
            writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
            writer.setSql("UPDATE db3.user_purge SET purge_status = 'S', del_date = NOW() WHERE user_id = :userId");
            writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return writer;
        }
}
```

StopListener.java
This ChunkListner class implementation is used to terminate the execution any time other than between 10pm and 6am

```
public class StopListener implements ChunkListener{
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    
    @Autowired
    AppUtils appUtils;
    
    @Override
    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        if (stopJob()) {
            this.stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();            
        }       
    }
    
    @Override
    public void afterChunkError(ChunkContext context) {
                
    }

    //Check the time between 10pm and 6am
    private boolean terminateJob() {
        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); 
        calendar.setTime(date); 
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) >= 6 
                && calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 22) {           
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And finally my scheduler method in application class. I am using CommandLneRunner to accept arguments.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class UserPurgeBatchApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(UserPurgeBatchApplication.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobOperator jobOperator;
    
    private String jobName;
    private JobParameters jobParameters;
    private String inputFile;
    private String usertype;
    private boolean jobStatus = false;
    private String completionStatus;    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(UserPurgeBatchApplication.class, args);           
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        this.jobName = args[0];
        
        this.jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
                
        
        LOG.info("||| Launching the JOB: " + jobName);  
        this.completionStatus  = jobSelector(jobName, jobParameters).getExitCode();
        LOG.info(">>> JOB completed with status: " + this.completionStatus);
    }


    public ExitStatus jobSelector(String jobName, JobParameters jobParameters) {        
        Job job = this.context.getBean(jobName, Job.class);
        
        try {
            return this.jobLauncher.run(job,  jobParameters).getExitStatus();
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | 
                JobRestartException | 
                JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | 
                JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return new ExitStatus("FAILED");
    }
    
    
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 22-23,23,0-6 * * *")
    public void batchStartScheduler() {
        LOG.info("---Beginning of batchScheduler()---");
        
        Long lastExecutionID = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(jobName, jobParameters).getId();
        String jobStatus = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(jobName, jobParameters).getStatus().toString();
        Job job = this.context.getBean(jobName, Job.class);
        
        if(!jobStatus.equals(ApplicationConstants.JOB_EXITSTATUS_COMPLETED)) {
            if(jobStatus.equals(ApplicationConstants.JOB_EXITSTATUS_STOPPED) 
                    || jobStatus.equals(ApplicationConstants.JOB_EXITSTATUS_FAILED)) {
                    
                try {
                LOG.info("|||Starting the Job...");
                    this.jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder(jobParameters)
                            .addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .toJobParameters();
                    
                    this.jobLauncher.run(job,  jobParameters);
                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException
                        | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else {
            LOG.info("Scheduler not executed!!");           
        }
                
        LOG.info("---End of batchScheduler()---");
    }
    
}
```

There are some confusions.
Will run method always try to restart the previous executions if it is failed? Because I could see this was still restarting and that can be the reason for this. I tried to provide new JobParameter hoping it will just launch it again. I hope my stopping method from ChunkListener is ok. But somehow I want to start this job again from Scheduler and I definitely need a multihreaded step. I also hope a CompositeWriter in a Multithreaded step is also fine. A help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update**
: Finally I could make it work by adding reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false). But I think I need to use thread safe Reader as suggested by Mahmoud Ben Hassine. So I am trying to use JdbcPagingItemReader but getting error as "sortKey must be specified". I think I have specified it but not sure it is correct. Here is my JdbcPagingItemReader

```
@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<UserInfo> jdbcPagingItemReader() {
    JdbcPagingItemReader<UserInfo> pagingItemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

    pagingItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    pagingItemReader.setFetchSize(3);
    pagingItemReader.setRowMapper(new SoftDeleteMapper());

    MySqlPagingQueryProvider mySqlPagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
    mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT user_id, user_status");
    mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM db3.user_purge");
    mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setWhereClause( "WHERE user_status = 'I' "
                                                + "AND purge_status = 'N'");

    Map<String, Order> orderByKeys = new HashMap<>();
    orderByKeys.put("user_id", Order.ASCENDING);

    mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(orderByKeys);
    pagingItemReader.setQueryProvider(mySqlPagingQueryProvider);

    return pagingItemReader;
}
```

My Updated Step

```
@Bean
public Step userPurgeStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("userPurgeStep")
            .<UserInfo, UserInfo> chunk(10)
            .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader())
            .writer(compositeSoftDelWriter())
            .listener(new StopListener())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-threading is not compatible with restarts. As mentioned in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html#setSaveState-boolean-), you should set `saveState` to false if you use the `JdbcCursorItemReader` in a multi-threaded step.

Moreover, the `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread-safe as it wraps a `ResultSet` object which is not thread safe and also because it inherits from `AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader` which is [not thread safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.html) neither. So using it in a multi-threaded step is incorrect. This is actually the cause of your issue `Unexpected cursor position change`. Concurrent threads are modifying the cursor position inadvertently.

You need to synchronize access to the reader by wrapping it in a `SynchronizedIteamStreamReader` or use a `JdbcPagingItemReader` which [is thread safe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html).

**EDIT:** Add example with `JdbcPagingItemReader`

Here is a self-contained docker-based sample:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.ClassRule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.Order;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.MySqlPagingQueryProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class SO67614305 {

    private static final DockerImageName MYSQL_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("mysql:8.0.24");

    @ClassRule
    public static MySQLContainer<?> mysql = new MySQLContainer<>(MYSQL_IMAGE);
    
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private Job job;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        String schema = "/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql";
        String data = // the script is inline here to have a self contained example
                "create table person (ID int not null primary key, name varchar(20));" +
                "insert into person values (1, 'foo1'); insert into person values (2, 'foo2');" +
                "insert into person values (3, 'foo3'); insert into person values (4, 'foo4');";
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource(schema));
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ByteArrayResource(data.getBytes()));
        databasePopulator.execute(this.dataSource);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        // given
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
        
        // when
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncher.run(this.job, jobParameters);

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
            MysqlDataSource datasource = new MysqlDataSource();
            datasource.setURL(mysql.getJdbcUrl());
            datasource.setUser(mysql.getUsername());
            datasource.setPassword(mysql.getPassword());
            datasource.setUseSSL(false);
            return datasource;
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> jdbcPagingItemReader() throws Exception {
            MySqlPagingQueryProvider mySqlPagingQueryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
            mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSelectClause("SELECT id, name");
            mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setFromClause("FROM person");
            Map<String, Order> orderByKeys = new HashMap<>();
            orderByKeys.put("id", Order.DESCENDING);
            mySqlPagingQueryProvider.setSortKeys(orderByKeys);

            JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> pagingItemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
            pagingItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource());
            pagingItemReader.setFetchSize(2);
            pagingItemReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
            pagingItemReader.setQueryProvider(mySqlPagingQueryProvider);
            return pagingItemReader;
        }

        @Bean
        public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) throws Exception {
            return jobs.get("job")
                    .start(steps.get("step").chunk(2)
                            .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader())
                            .writer(items -> items.forEach(System.out::println))
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }

        static class Person {
            int id;
            String name;

            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Person{" +
                        "id=" + id +
                        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                        '}';
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This prints items in the descending order as expected without complaining about the missing sort key:

```
Person{id=4, name='foo4'}
Person{id=3, name='foo3'}
Person{id=2, name='foo2'}
Person{id=1, name='foo1'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Its really helped but I was facing issues with JdbcPagingItemReader. It says sortkey must be provided. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Please see my updates. Hope you can help me. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I see nothing wrong with your config, you have set the sort key correctly so I'm not sure why it is not seeing it. I added an example with a similar setup as yours and I don't have the error. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the issue was with my IDE it somehow was not setting the sortKey. I ran thee same test you shared and it works like a charm. Thank you very much for all your help, really appreciated!